# ValueError: Data must be positive (boxcox scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution

I'm trying to transform my dataset to a normal distribution.

```
0      8.298511e-03
1      3.055319e-01
2      6.938647e-02
3      2.904091e-02
4      7.422441e-02
5      6.074046e-02
6      9.265747e-04
7      7.521846e-02
8      5.960521e-02
9      7.405019e-04
10     3.086551e-02
11     5.444835e-02
12     2.259236e-02
13     4.691038e-02
14     6.463911e-02
15     2.172805e-02
16     8.210005e-02
17     2.301189e-02
18     4.073898e-07
19     4.639910e-02
20     1.662777e-02
21     8.662539e-02
22     4.436425e-02
23     4.557591e-02
24     3.499897e-02
25     2.788340e-02
26     1.707958e-02
27     1.506404e-02
28     3.207647e-02
29     2.147011e-03
30     2.972746e-02
31     1.028140e-01
32     2.183737e-02
33     9.063370e-03
34     3.070437e-02
35     1.477440e-02
36     1.036309e-02
37     2.000609e-01
38     3.366233e-02
39     1.479767e-03
40     1.137169e-02
41     1.957088e-02
42     4.921303e-03
43     4.279257e-02
44     4.363429e-02
45     1.040123e-01
46     2.930958e-02
47     1.935434e-03
48     1.954418e-02
49     2.980253e-02
50     3.643772e-02
51     3.411437e-02
52     4.976063e-02
53     3.704608e-02
54     7.044161e-02
55     8.101365e-03
56     9.310477e-03
57     7.626637e-02
58     8.149728e-03
59     4.157399e-01
60     8.200258e-02
61     2.844295e-02
62     1.046601e-01
63     6.565680e-02
64     9.825436e-04
65     9.353639e-02
66     6.535298e-02
67     6.979044e-04
68     2.772859e-02
69     4.378422e-02
70     2.020185e-02
71     4.774493e-02
72     6.346146e-02
73     2.466264e-02
74     6.636585e-02
75     2.548934e-02
76     1.113937e-06
77     5.723409e-02
78     1.533288e-02
79     1.027341e-01
80     4.294570e-02
81     4.844853e-02
82     5.579620e-02
83     2.531824e-02
84     1.661426e-02
85     1.430836e-02
86     3.157232e-02
87     2.241722e-03
88     2.946256e-02
89     1.038383e-01
90     1.868837e-02
91     8.854596e-03
92     2.391759e-02
93     1.612714e-02
94     1.007823e-02
95     1.975513e-01
96     3.581289e-02
97     1.199747e-03
98     1.263381e-02
99     1.966746e-02
100    4.040786e-03
101    4.497264e-02
102    4.030524e-02
103    8.627087e-02
104    3.248317e-02
105    5.727582e-03
106    1.781355e-02
107    2.377991e-02
108    4.299568e-02
109    3.664353e-02
110    5.167902e-02
111    4.006848e-02
112    7.072990e-02
113    6.744938e-03
114    1.064900e-02
115    9.823497e-02
116    8.992714e-03
117    1.792453e-01
118    6.817763e-02
119    2.588843e-02
120    1.048027e-01
121    6.468491e-02
122    1.035536e-03
123    8.800684e-02
124    5.975065e-02
125    7.365861e-04
126    4.209485e-02
127    4.232421e-02
128    2.371866e-02
129    5.894714e-02
130    7.177195e-02
131    2.116566e-02
132    7.579219e-02
133    3.174744e-02
134    0.000000e+00
135    5.786439e-02
136    1.458493e-02
137    9.820156e-02
138    4.373873e-02
139    4.271649e-02
140    5.532575e-02
141    2.311324e-02
142    1.644508e-02
143    1.328273e-02
144    3.908473e-02
145    2.355468e-03
146    2.519321e-02
147    1.131868e-01
148    1.708967e-02
149    1.027661e-02
150    2.439899e-02
151    1.604058e-02
152    1.134323e-02
153    2.247722e-01
154    3.408590e-02
155    2.222239e-03
156    1.659830e-02
157    2.284733e-02
158    4.618550e-03
159    3.674162e-02
160    4.131283e-02
161    8.846273e-02
162    2.504404e-02
163    6.004396e-03
164    1.986309e-02
165    2.347111e-02
166    3.865636e-02
167    3.672307e-02
168    6.658419e-02
169    3.726879e-02
170    7.600138e-02
171    7.184871e-03
172    1.142840e-02
173    9.741311e-02
174    8.165448e-03
175    1.529210e-01
176    6.648081e-02
177    2.617601e-02
178    9.547816e-02
179    6.857775e-02
180    8.129399e-04
181    7.107914e-02
182    5.884794e-02
183    8.398721e-04
184    6.972981e-02
185    4.461767e-02
186    2.264404e-02
187    5.566633e-02
188    6.595136e-02
189    2.301914e-02
190    7.488919e-02
191    3.108619e-02
192    4.989364e-07
193    4.834949e-02
194    1.422578e-02
195    9.398186e-02
196    4.870391e-02
197    3.841369e-02
198    6.406801e-02
199    2.603315e-02
200    1.692629e-02
201    1.409982e-02
202    4.099215e-02
203    2.093724e-03
204    2.640732e-02
205    1.032129e-01
206    1.581881e-02
207    8.977325e-03
208    1.941141e-02
209    1.502126e-02
210    9.923589e-03
211    2.757357e-01
212    3.096234e-02
213    4.388900e-03
214    1.784778e-02
215    2.179550e-02
216    3.944159e-03
217    3.703552e-02
218    4.033897e-02
219    1.157076e-01
220    2.400446e-02
221    5.761179e-03
222    1.899621e-02
223    2.401468e-02
224    4.458745e-02
225    3.357898e-02
226    5.331003e-02
227    3.488753e-02
228    7.466599e-02
229    6.075236e-03
230    9.815318e-03
231    9.598735e-02
232    7.103607e-03
233    1.100602e-01
234    5.677641e-02
235    2.420500e-02
236    9.213369e-02
237    4.024043e-02
238    6.987694e-04
239    8.612055e-02
240    5.663353e-02
241    4.871693e-04
242    4.533811e-02
243    3.593244e-02
244    1.982537e-02
245    5.490786e-02
246    5.603109e-02
247    1.671653e-02
248    6.522711e-02
249    3.341356e-02
250    2.378629e-06
251    4.299939e-02
252    1.223163e-02
253    8.392798e-02
254    4.272826e-02
255    3.183946e-02
256    4.431299e-02
257    2.661024e-02
258    1.686707e-02
259    4.070924e-03
260    3.325947e-02
261    2.023611e-03
262    2.402284e-02
263    8.369778e-02
264    1.375093e-02
265    8.899898e-03
266    2.148740e-02
267    1.301483e-02
268    8.355791e-03
269    2.549934e-01
270    2.792516e-02
271    4.652563e-03
272    1.556313e-02
273    1.936942e-02
274    3.547794e-03
275    3.412516e-02
276    3.932606e-02
277    5.305868e-02
278    2.354438e-02
279    5.379380e-03
280    1.904203e-02
281    2.045495e-02
282    3.275855e-02
283    3.007389e-02
284    8.227664e-02
285    2.479949e-02
286    6.573835e-02
287    5.165842e-03
288    7.599650e-03
289    9.613557e-02
290    6.690175e-03
291    1.779880e-01
292    5.076263e-02
293    3.117607e-02
294    7.495692e-02
295    3.707768e-02
296    7.086975e-04
297    8.935981e-02
298    5.624249e-02
299    7.105331e-04
300    3.339868e-02
301    3.354603e-02
302    2.041988e-02
303    3.862522e-02
304    5.977081e-02
305    1.730081e-02
306    6.909621e-02
307    3.729478e-02
308    3.940647e-07
309    4.385336e-02
310    1.391891e-02
311    8.898305e-02
312    3.840141e-02
313    3.214408e-02
314    4.284080e-02
315    1.841022e-02
316    1.528207e-02
317    3.106559e-03
318    3.945481e-02
319    2.085094e-03
320    2.464190e-02
321    7.844914e-02
322    1.526590e-02
323    9.922147e-03
324    1.649218e-02
325    1.341602e-02
326    8.124446e-03
327    2.867380e-01
328    2.663867e-02
329    5.342012e-03
330    1.752612e-02
331    2.010863e-02
332    3.581845e-03
333    3.652284e-02
334    4.484362e-02
335    4.600939e-02
336    2.213280e-02
337    5.494917e-03
338    2.016594e-02
339    2.118010e-02
340    2.964000e-02
341    3.405549e-02
342    1.014185e-01
343    2.451624e-02
344    7.966998e-02
345    5.301538e-03
346    8.198895e-03
347    8.789368e-02
348    7.222417e-03
349    1.448276e-01
350    5.676056e-02
351    2.987054e-02
352    6.851434e-02
353    4.193034e-02
354    7.025054e-03
355    8.557358e-02
356    5.812736e-02
357    2.263676e-02
358    2.922588e-02
359    3.363161e-02
360    1.495056e-02
361    5.871619e-02
362    6.235094e-02
363    1.691340e-02
364    5.361939e-02
365    3.722318e-02
366    9.828477e-03
367    4.155345e-02
368    1.327760e-02
369    7.205372e-02
370    4.151130e-02
371    3.265365e-02
372    2.879418e-02
373    2.314340e-02
374    1.653692e-02
375    1.077611e-02
376    3.481427e-02
377    1.815487e-03
378    2.232305e-02
379    1.005192e-01
380    1.491262e-02
381    3.752658e-02
382    1.271613e-02
383    1.223707e-02
384    8.088923e-03
385    2.572550e-01
386    2.300194e-02
387    2.847960e-02
388    1.782098e-02
389    1.900759e-02
390    3.647629e-03
391    3.723368e-02
392    4.079514e-02
393    5.510332e-02
394    3.072313e-02
395    4.183566e-03
396    1.891549e-02
397    1.870293e-02
398    3.182769e-02
399    4.167840e-02
400    1.343152e-01
401    2.451973e-02
402    7.567017e-02
403    4.837843e-03
404    6.477297e-03
405    7.664675e-02
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

This is the code I used for transforming dataset:

```
from scipy import stats
x,_ = stats.boxcox(df)
```

I get this error:

```
            if any(x <= 0):
-> 1031         raise ValueError("Data must be positive.")
   1032 
   1033     if lmbda is not None:  # single transformation

ValueError: Data must be positive
```

Is it because my values are too small that it's producing an error? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. New to using boxcox, could be using it incorrectly in this example. Open to suggestions and alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the df object you're passing in? Is it a data frame? Could it be that boxcox is using that first column of indices and throwing an error as a result of the first element being equal to 0?

Comment: It's a dataframe with a single column. I've done this with other dataframes with larger values and I didn't have this issue. I don't believe the index column is producing the error

Comment: My mistake, see Warren's answer. It appears you did have a value of zero in there, I just missed it because I didn't think it would be written in that kind of notation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your data contains the value 0 (at index 134).  When `boxcox` says the data must be positive, it means *strictly* positive.

What is the meaning of your data?  Does 0 make sense?  Is that 0 actually a very small number that was rounded down to 0?

You could simply discard that 0.  Alternatively, you could do something like the following.  (This amounts to temporarily discarding the 0, and then using -1/λ for the transformed value of 0, where λ is the Box-Cox transformation parameter.)

First, create some data that contains one 0 (all other values are positive):

```
In [13]: np.random.seed(8675309)

In [14]: data = np.random.gamma(1, 1, size=405)

In [15]: data[100] = 0
```

(In your code, you would replace that with, say, `data = df.values`.)

Copy the strictly positive data to `posdata`:

```
In [16]: posdata = data[data > 0]
```

Find the optimal Box-Cox transformation, and verify that λ is positive.  This work-around doesn't work if λ ≤ 0.

```
In [17]: bcdata, lam = boxcox(posdata)

In [18]: lam
Out[18]: 0.244049919975582
```

Make a new array to hold that result, along with the limiting value of the transform of 0 (which is -1/λ):

```
In [19]: x = np.empty_like(data)

In [20]: x[data > 0] = bcdata

In [21]: x[data == 0] = -1/lam
```

The following plot shows the histograms of `data` and `x`.

[image: plot]

Comment: will it be incorrect to scale the data before attempting a boxcox transformation

Comment: What is the purpose of `np.empty_like(data)`?

Answer (score 10):

Rather than normal boxcox, you can use boxcox1p. It adds 1 to x so there won't be any "0" record

```
from scipy.special import boxcox1p
scipy.special.boxcox1p(x, lmbda)
```

For more info check out the docs at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox1p.html

Comment: What should I use for lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Is your data that you are sending to `boxcox` 1-dimensional `ndarray`?

Second way could be adding shift parameter by summing `shift` (see details from the link) to all of the `ndarray` elements before sending it to boxcox and subtracting `shift` from the resulting array elements (if I have understood `boxcox` algorithm correctly, that could be solution in your case, too).

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html