# ValueError: Data must not be constant

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to transform my data using boxcox transformation. As there's the value 0 I consider the following approach found in [ValueError: Data must be positive (boxcox scipy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180988/valueerror-data-must-be-positive-boxcox-scipy) But now i am getting value error says Data must not be constant. Here's my approach:

```
posdata = df1[df1['hotel'] > 0]['hotel']
bcdata, lam = boxcox(posdata)
bc = np.empty_like(df1['hotel'])
bc[df1['hotel'] > 0] = bcdata
bc[df1['hotel'] == 0] = -1/lam
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-551b3ccca575> in <module>
  1 posdata = df1[df1['hotel'] > 0]['hotel']
  2 bcdata, lam = boxcox(posdata)
  3 bc = np.empty_like(df1['hotel'])
  4 bc[df1['hotel'] > 0] = bcdata
  5 bc[df1['hotel'] == 0] = -1/lam

  ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py in boxcox(x, lmbda, alpha)
  1040 
  1041     if np.all(x == x[0]):
  1042         raise ValueError("Data must not be constant.")
  1043 
  1044     if any(x <= 0):

  ValueError: Data must not be constant.
```

Comment: what are the contents of posdata

Comment: posdata is just a variable that has a series extracted from df1's hotel column. check the 1st line of the code. The contents are integer values.

Comment: It says that all your `postdata` values are the same, but `boxcox` need values to be different. You can check that all values are the same like `print(postdata.unique())` after the first line.

Comment: @V.Ayrat thanks man I got it . Unfortunately I have taken the wrong column whose values are 0 and 1 and as i am taking values greater than 0, there's only the values 1 left. that's why it's giving me the error not to be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sklearn` and reshape your data in column vector:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer

fit = PowerTransformer(
   method = 'box-cox',
   scale = False,
)

transform = fit.fit(
   np.array(data).reshape(-1, 1)
)
```